# Using Hugin and libpano13 in an iron.io worker

Tags: iron.io, ironworker

I would like to use an iron.io worker to stich panoramas and create HDRs using the OpenSource Hugin and libpano13 toolkits. The programs needed are all command-line (no GUI is needed) but I'm not entirely sure how I go about building a worker that includes the correct binaries for using the Hugin panotools.

Can I pre-compile the right binaries for the iron.io worker OS (Ubuntu Linux)? I can create a VM and install Ubuntu on it to get a set of binaries built that I include in my worker. But is there a better way using the "build" directive in the worker file? The problem I see right away is that Hugin is a cmake-based build so I'd need to create something that uses autoconf/automake, right?

I don't really need all of Hugin, either. I just need the control point finder utility and the enfuse/enblend utilities for doing the actual stitching. I don't need any of the GUI stuff, which is wxWidgets based.

Can anyone shed light on how I would go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You really need only statically compiled x64 binaries, find them anywhere - and you're done.

Possible solutions:

- Install stuff on local Ubuntu x64 (IronWorker using 12.04 TLS x64) and include required files into worker's package (which is just .zip file after uploading) (and probably extend PATH at start of a worker)
- Use `build` command to do any installation procedures remotely (you're still limited to non-root operations though)
- Use `deb` command to install existing .deb packages.

.worker file example (including custom version of imagemagick):

```
runtime 'binary'
exec 'run.sh'
full_remote_build true
deb 'http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5_6.7.7.10-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb'
deb 'http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand5_6.7.7.10-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb'
deb 'http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb'
```