# How to install Hugin-2016.2.0 in cent os 6.8?

Tags: linux, cmake, centos, hugin, vigra

Recently i have tried to install Hugin-2010 in Centos 6.8, but it says to install Hugin 2010 I required panotools 13 and unfortunately i am not able to install same on CentOS 6.8, so I thought let's try with Hugin-2016 but now it says

```
 "CMake Error at CMakeModules/FindVIGRA.cmake:55 
(MESSAGE):Could not find vigra/configVersion.hxx or vigra/config_version.hxx. Your vigra installation seems to be corrupt."
```

So I am stucked how to install and configure this?

I have already search for this question but no result found for CentOS, However i have found one result for Ubuntu as below link but it was of no use in CentOS.
Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

[Using Hugin and libpano13 in an iron.io worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615046/using-hugin-and-libpano13-in-an-iron-io-worker)

Comment: What is not clear here? It requires VIGRA Computer Vision Library, which it cannot find.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking into the same thing here this morning. I think in order to install Hugin into CentOS, you might find your way by yourself. Because you might be the very first one to do so.

As what Hugin said in their page, CentOS is not a supported platform shown in the list.
http://wiki.panotools.org/Development_of_Open_Source_tools#Build_your_Own_Test_Builds

What I would do is that, follows the instruction for Fedora, try to install and compile Hugin onto CentOS. (As CentOS and Fedora are both under Red Hat Family.)
http://wiki.panotools.org/Hugin_Compiling_Fedora